# Can I Save Dwarf Fortress Without Quitting

Tags: dwarf-fortress

Dwarf fortress automatically quits the game after saving (with the exception of autosaves) and then loading it up again takes a while. So saving frequently is really inconvenient, however, due to how unstable the game is at the moment, I find it necessary to do so. 
As such, is it possible to either autosave more than seasonally, or save without quitting?
I'm open to modding the game to achieve this!

Comment: Are you asking this to safeguard against the possibility of losing your fortress? Where's the [Fun](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/v0.34:Losing) in that?

Comment: I'm well aware of the concept of Fun, but losing because of a game crash is hardly the same as losing because a massive army of elves comes and slaughters you, or you break an aquifer and flood the place

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are two other save game options in Dwarf Fortress besides *Save and Quit*:

- [Autosave](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Technical_tricks#Save_Behavior), to save your game at regular intervals;
- [Quicksave](https://github.com/DFHack/dfhack#quicksave), to save your game at an arbitrary point.

Autosave can be configured in your `d_init.txt` file to save at the beginning of every year or every season, or to turn off autosaving entirely. If Autosave is on, it can be configured to back up your previous save game before saving.

Quicksave is not part of the game by default, but is added by **DFHack**. You switch to the DFHack terminal screen and type `quicksave` to save the game immediately.

Comment: You sir are a beautiful man, thankyou

Comment: I'd expect that DFHack have something like this but wasn't sure. Good job :)